# VBS for Excel to count and specific word and use it for a loop

Tags: excel, loops, vbscript

I need little help again.

I have an excel file and I have to do some formatting for further processing.
I stuck at one point:

- find a word / or string
- get back the number how often it is used in the excel
- use this number to put it into a loop

I hope this is possible with VBscript, because I cannot use VBA.
This is how the code looks like, but I doesn't work

```
Dim objExcel  
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
Excel.Visible = True  
excel.workbooks.open "C:\Users\............."  
excel.Rows("1:34").Select  
excel.Selection.Delete  
excel.Columns("A:A").Select  
excel.Selection.Delete  
excel.Range("A1").Select  
Number = excel.countIf "A:A", "Ent.Date"  
for i = 1 to Number  
  excel.Cells.Find("Ent.Date").Activate  
  excel.Activecell.Offset(-1,0).Select  
  excel.Activecell.resize(RowSize +3).EntireRow.Select  
  excel.Selection.Delete  
next
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain "it doesn't work" by detailing what you are trying to achieve, and what your code is doing that is different to what you want.  See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. `CountIf()` is a method of the `WorksheetFunction` class in your `Excel` application. So:

```
Number = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf("A:A", "Ent.Date")
```

Unrelated. All of this `.Active` `.Select` is unnecessary. Humans `Select` and `Activate`, but your script doesn't need to.

Instead:

```
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
Excel.Visible = True  
excel.workbooks.open "C:\Users\............."  
excel.Rows("1:34").Delete    
excel.Columns("A:A").Delete
Number = excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Excel.Range("A:A"), "Ent.Date")
for i = 1 to Number  
  excel.Cells.Find("Ent.Date").Offset(-1,0).resize(RowSize +3).EntireRow.Delete       
next
```

Also (and this might be more preference) instead of looping with `For` you could instead us a `While` loop:

```
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
Excel.Visible = True  
excel.workbooks.open "C:\Users\............."  
excel.Rows("1:34").Delete    
excel.Columns("A:A").Delete
Do While excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Excel.Range("A:A"), "Ent.Date") >= 1      
  excel.Cells.Find("Ent.Date").Offset(-1,0).resize(RowSize +3).EntireRow.Delete       
Loop
```

That causes a little extra overhead since it runs that countif on each loop, but it feels more succinct and less potential for error since you seem to be resizing the range returned by `Find()` to be more rows and then deleting them all... which means you might be picking off rows that also contain your search criteria, which means you are looping too much in your `For` Loop. But... perhaps your sheet is set up in such a way that this condition doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but when I use your code, everytime I get the error messages (sorry I have to translate it to english as I am from austria):  Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub Error 800A0414 VBS

Comment: Perhaps take off the parantheses for that `countif()` function, much like you have it in your original code. something like:  `Excel.WorksheetFunction.Countif "A:A", "Ent.Date"`

Comment: Thanks again, but without the () I get the error code 800A0401 Excpected End of Statement. I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: I wasn't able to get the same error when doing a quick test. I did update the code to qualify that `"A:A"` range. Give it another spin and see if you get past the error you were seeing.